# Initialize and use Swup in Meteor js

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, swup

I am trying to use swup in meteor js framework.
I added the script tag that contains unpkg link for swup in main.html and initialized Swup in Meteor.startup function of main.js.
But when i run the app, it is throwing "Cannot set property 'responseURL' of null" error.

in main.html:

```
<script src="unpkg.com/swup@latest/dist/swup.min.js"></script>  
<script>
    const swup = new Swup();
</script>
```

And added swup id to layout.html which is like the container in which all routing occurs.

I just recently started to work on Meteor, so i am a bit confused. I would be glad, if anyone could help me in initializing and setting up swup.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please share your code with us

Comment: Added 
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swup@latest/dist/swup.min.js"></script> and  
<script>const swup = new Swup();</script>  to main.html.
And added swup id to layout.html which is like the container in which all routing occurs.
If i run that, then i get the error i mentioned above.

Comment: It's good practice to edit your original question to show the code - then it can be formatted for readability.

Comment: I edited the question for you. Are you using React or Blaze?

Comment: @Mikkel Thank You. I am relatively new to stackoverflow...:D
I am using Blaze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blaze strips any `script` tag including it's content to prevent XSS. Install swup via npm and import it in your Template to resolve this:

```sh
$ meteor npm install --save swup
```

and in your `client/main.js` you initialize swup:

```js
import Swup from 'swup';
const swup = new Swup();
```